Why is PinchGestureHandler not zooming in on expo sdk 50?
I have a camera component using expo-camera. I have two buttons that tap to zoom in and out, both work perfectly fine. But I want to implement pinch to zoom using react-native-gesture-handler.
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import {
  PinchGestureHandler,
  GestureHandlerRootView,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";

const CameraComponent = ({
  setCam,
  closeCamera,
  takePicture,
  flash,
  type,
  handleFlash,
}) => {
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(true);
  const [focusSquare, setFocusSquare] = useState({
    visible: false,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });
// Here is the function called by the gesture handler
  const handleZoom = (event) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.scale > 1 && zoom < 1) {
      setZoom(zoom + 0.001);
    }
    if (event.nativeEvent.scale < 1 && zoom > 0) {
      setZoom(zoom - 0.001);
    }
  };

  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(0);

  const focusCamera = (event) => {
    const { locationX, locationY } = event.nativeEvent;
    setFocusSquare({ visible: true, x: locationX, y: locationY });
    setFocus(false);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setFocus(true);
      setFocusSquare({ visible: false, x: 0, y: 0 });
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleZoomIn = () => {
    setZoom(zoom + 0.001);
  };

  const handleZoomOut = () => {
    setZoom(Math.max(0, zoom - 0.01));
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={handleFlash}
        style={styles.flash}
        testID="flash"
      >
        <Text>
          {flash ? (
            <Icon name="flash-on" size={40} />
          ) : (
            <Icon name="flash-off" size={40} />
          )}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <PinchGestureHandler onGestureEvent={handleZoom}>
            <Camera
              ref={(ref) => setCam(ref)}
              style={styles.fixedRatio}
              type={type}
              flashMode={flash}
              autoFocus={focus}
              zoom={zoom}
            />
          </PinchGestureHandler>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
      
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 20,
            left: 20,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 5,
          }}
          onPress={handleZoomIn}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "#FFF" }}>Zoom In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 20,
            right: 20,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 5,
          }}
          onPress={handleZoomOut}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "#FFF" }}>Zoom Out</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", padding: 40 }}
      >
        {/* Capture Button */}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePicture} testID="takePicture">
          <Text>
            <Icon name="camera" size={50} />
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          testID="closeCamera"
          onPress={closeCamera}
          style={{ marginTop: 5 }}
        >
          <Text>
            <Icon name="cancel" size={30} />
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};


export default CameraComponent;


